# get multiple column from both table by joining a table on the basis of other max table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

1) vendor table

```
--------------------------------------------
   VENDid    VENDname 
   ---      ----- 
    1        ABC
    2        XYZ
    3        WXY
```

2)purchase table

```
---------------------------------------------  
VENDid   Purchasedate
------   ------------
1         12-01-2012
1         10-11-2013
2         22-02-2014
2         11-04-2014
3         10-05-2014
3         11-06-2014
1         14-06-2014
```

output(list all rows of vendor table and only max(purchasedate) from purchase table)

```
---------------------------------------------
VENDid     VENDname     PurchaseDate
-------    --------     -------------
1          ABC          14-06-2014 
2          XYZ          11-04-2014    
3          WXY          11-06-2014
```

i got some queries like to solve previous problem-

```
SELECT v.VendID, VendName, Max(PurchaseDate)
FROM vendor v
INNER JOIN purchase p
ON v.VendID = p.VendID
Group By v.VendID, VendName


select VENDid, VENDname, 
 (select top 1 purchaseDate from purchase p 
  where p.VENDid=v.VENDid order by purchaseDate desc) as 'Purchase date' 
from Vendor v
```

Que. If i will add some more column in purchase table like -

2)purchase table

```
------------------------------------------    
    VENDid   Purchasedate   amount_paid
    ------   ------------   ------------
    1         12-01-2012    10000
    1         10-11-2013    20000
    2         22-02-2014    15000 
    2         11-04-2014    30000 
    3         10-05-2014    80000
    3         11-06-2014    17000
    1         14-06-2014    28000
```

and i want amount_paid  along with previous output like-

```
---------------------------------------------
VENDid     VENDname     PurchaseDate     amount_paid
-------    --------     -------------    -------------
1          ABC          14-06-2014        28000
2          XYZ          11-04-2014        30000
3          WXY          11-06-2014        17000
```

then what will be query..

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using SQL Server.  If so, you can use `cross apply`:

```
select v.VENDid, v.VENDname, p.PurchaseDate, p.Amount_Paid
from Vendor v cross apply
     (select top 1 p.*
      from purchase p 
      where p.VENDid = v.VENDid
      order by p.purchaseDate desc
     ) p ;
```